# How can I filter '?' out of XML?

Tags: xml, perl

I have some XML data like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
  <b>someone ? messed up</b>
  <c>this question mark has to disappear too?</c>
</a>
```

Now my object is to validate if every opening tag has a closing one, and to filter out the question marks in between `<b>` tags using Perl.

I tried different variations of

```
$_[0] =~ s|>(.*)\?(.*)<|>$1$2<|g;
```

but this only cuts off `<?` and `?>`. How can I get this to work without ruining the XML version tag? Also, would using [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) be overkill just for checking if all tags are closed properly?

Comment: Are you generating the XML, or trying to fix some broken XML that someone gave you? For the former - why not just use an XML parser to do it for you, and then it doesn't matter.

Comment: I have to fix some broken XML which is generated elsewhere

Comment: I'd use a better-supported method like trying to parse it into a structure using something like [`XML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Parser), and balking if it fails. Typically "in the wild", malformed XML is treated as invalid, so you shouldn't be trying to correct it. Sorry if that's not helpful.

Comment: For the questionmarks, they have to be fixed. If some tags are missing, script should just alarm and not fix

Comment: Offically - the XML spec says malformed documents are invalid, and you should simply reject them. If you think about it, this makes sense - 'fixing' a data format is potentially dangerous. If I were parsing, I'd use XML::Twig.

Comment: Do you want to remove the `?` in all text nodes, or just those that are descendants of a `b` element?

Comment: The XML that you have posted is fine. I'm not clear what you're asking about, but I hope you know that question marks `?` are fine within text nodes? If you have unbalanced tags in your *real* data then it's impossible to fix in the general case. Perhaps you should show us some data that has the problems you're trying to fix.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Don't think removing the `regex` tag stopped the OP from using it. Its peoples choice.

Comment: @sln I didn't remove it to stop the OP from using regexes, I removed it because it's unnecessary. I also would have removed tags like `text-parsing`, `validation`, and `questionmark`. Solutions are free to use regexes whether the tag is there or not.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Yeah, I didn't mean to insinuate you alone changed the context of the original post, guess others modified it too. It should have been left intact with flaws. `cuts off <? and ?>` - not only not true, was never in the original. `question marks in between <b> tags ` - OP's original was all tags. The original statement was his regex was messing up version tags, that wasn't true either, but some grabbed onto it. His regex was flawed - it used greedy quantifiers that grabbed tags. Take it for what it is, fix broken XML - no, fix `?` with regex - _YES_.

Comment: @sln Check the Markdown in the original version of the question. The OP didn't use code tags around `<b>`, `<?`, and `?>`, so they were interpreted as HTML and hidden. If you do a side-by-side comparison of the Markdown in my edit, you'll see I didn't change the meaning of the question, just fixed grammar and added formatting.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - Ok, saw the original `<? and ?>`. I still think this should have been left flawed, sometimes you catch extra meaning from flawed posts.

Comment: @sln I don't know what you mean by "should have been left flawed." You mean you think everybody should have answered a question that the OP didn't ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is probably not the best solution to *fix* XML.

To fix your regex for the question mark thing its this
kind of flawed regex.  Flawed because it only fixes a single `?`.

`s/>([^<>]*?)[ ]?\?[ ]?([^<>]+?)</>$1 $2</g`

```
 #  >([^<>]*?)[ ]?\?[ ]?([^<>]+?)<

 >
 ( [^<>]*? )
 [ ]? 
 \?
 [ ]? 
 ( [^<>]+? )
 <
```

Comment: Well thanks sln, but it just almost works.
it kills the question marks i havent gotten, but it does 

<?xml version="1.0"?<a>





edit:


i fixed your fix ;)
 $_[0]=~s/>(.*?)[ ]?\?[ ]?(.+?)</>$1$2</sg

thanks again ;)

Comment: Given you know where the 'version' tag exists, you could always delete it, purge question marks, re-insert it.

Comment: @chenino: Please explain your problem better. If you have malformed XML (although the example in your question is perfectly fine) then you mustn't try to fix it automatically. If it's valid XML but you want to remove any question marks in the text nodes, then you should use an XML library like [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) or [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::LibXML) to do it; any of them will ignore the XML declaration at the top of the file. ***Never*** use regular expressions to process XML as it is not a regular language.

Comment: You can sometimes 'get away' with munging XML by hand. But there are a lot of edge cases that'll burn you.

Comment: @Sobrique - What edge? I could throw down low/medium/high levels of regex to navigate content. Used his approach, because some will be afraid to use it.

Comment: @sln: I don't understand your comment. Are you saying it's perfectly fine to process any XML with regular expressions, as long as your patterns are smart enough?

Comment: @Borodin - What does `process any XML` mean?

Comment: @Brodin - XML parsing is an iterative process of levels, substitution and balanced elements. It can't be done with a regex. Parts of it can be done using regex, but not as a means to an end. In that respect, one of the levels is parsing the delimiters. Like this `/(?:<(?:(?:(\/*)($Name)\s*(\/*))|(?:($Name+)(\s+(?:(?:(?:".*?")|(?:'.*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+)\s*(\/?))|(?:\?(.*?)\?)|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE(.*?))|(?:\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\])|(?:--(.*?)--)|(?:ATTLIST(.*?))|(?:ENTITY(.*?))|(?:ELEMENT(.*?)))))>)|(.+?)/s`

Comment: @Borodin We have an XML as Ouptput, which is Input for another program, in this case XML is just the Interface. What we are trying to do is if some co-workers reedit something in the text, we want to find out if they destroyed something. So, ? have to be filtered out in the Text area, but thats all we are Fixing.Everything else will be just marked as destroyed, like if tags go missing. I was mistaken, that i want to do the parsing process with regex, just wanted to filter questionmarks with regex

Answer (score 4):

By definition - XML that's broken is broken and parsers should abort rather than trying to validate and fix. That's annoying at times, but it makes sense if you think about it - life's too short to be fixing malformed XML.

However I'd probably be looking towards [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.48/Twig.pm) as a module for XML processing. Cycling through each of your elements and deleting '?' from the text, whilst ignoring the XML structure. Perhaps not quite as concise as the other answers though.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new();
local $/;
$twig -> parse ( <DATA> );

my $element = $twig -> root; 

while ( $element = $element -> next_elt() ) {
    my $text_to_change = $element -> text;
    $text_to_change =~ s,\?,,g;
    $element -> set_content ( $text_to_change );
 }

$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented');
$twig -> print;


__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
    <b>someone ? messed up</b>
    <c>this question mark has to disappear too?</c>
</a>
```

We're using XML::Twig to parse your XML (which is valid, but contains question marks). 
Cycle through each element, extracting the element text - and therefore omitting tags and attributes such as the XML Doctype - and then amending it, before printing a reformatted indented chunk of XML. ('pretty' printing has a variety of formatting options).

This will error if you have broken tags, and tell you where they are, but it won't fix them.

Comment: `s,\?,,g` removes all question marks. And, he probably doesn't have valid XML, the processor will error.

Comment: Yeah, but the question asks about removing question marks, apart from those embedded in tags. Which this does. If the XML isn't valid, the processor will at least tell you where the error is. That can be trapped with `eval`.

Comment: His question about mid - `?` is actually very complex and not really solvable given linguistic nuance. As for fixing XML on errors .. good luck with that.

Answer (score 3):

> *Now my object is [...] to filter out the question marks in between `<b>` tags*

XML::LibXML solution:

```
for my $text_node ($doc->findnodes('//b//text()')) {
    my $text = $text_node->data();
    $text =~ s/\?//g;
    $text_node->setData($text);
}
```

---

If you have Perl 5.14+, that can be simplified to

```
for my $text_node ($doc->findnodes('//b//text()')) {
    $text_node->setData( $text_node->data() =~ s/\?//gr );
}
```

or

```
$_->setData( $_->data() =~ s/\?//gr )
   for $doc->findnodes('//b//text()');
```

Comment: (Replace `//b//text()` with `//text()` if you don't want to limit it to descendants of `b` elements.)